# Locating shapefile of European railways for goods transportion

Tags: data, europe, geomarketing

We are trying to make a project about European goods trade so we need railway data in shapefile format.

More specifically, we are trying to find the potential of mine products being exported from Turkey to Europe by using Geomarketing tools.

Basically, we need a European railways layer for ArcGIS (excluding passenger-only railways).

Comment: it might be helpful to specify in what detail the data should be and what you want to do with it in the project so that one can estimate what kind of data suits best.

Comment: Just a heads up. I downloaded and viewed these railroad and road network layers today (March 2020), and they are really bad, at least for Scandinavia. The road shapes do not align with the actual road network in many places (but in enough places that I know it is not a projection fault). The rail network is about 66% correct, but really, really wrong in the other 1/3. You should look elsewhere for transport layer data.

Answer (score 5):

[NaturalEarth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/) has a worldwide railroads layer. It maps the rail lines and has no indication of whether they are used for passenger or cargo travel.

Answer (score 3):

Found some information which might be of some use to you:

- Shapefile containing the majority of railroads in Europe (doesn't differentiate between passenger-only and trade-only railways)

http://www.mapcruzin.com/download-shapefile/europe-railways-shape.zip

[image: European railroad system]

Similar to above except you can download railroad shapefiles specifically by country

http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata

[image: Turkey railroad shapefile from DIVA-GIS]

- A PhD student (Z. Asligul Gocmen) did some work concerning the transporation networks in Turkey and looked at various historical and economical changes which occured. I included this purely out of interest, however there are references mentioned which could lead you to further information.

http://www-personal.umich.edu/~sarhaus/courses/NRE501_W1999/FINAL/ZGOCMEN/transportaionpaper.htm